# Mysql: Date as string

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a field in MySQL as varchar and need to do a select with a range. The date is in the following format "%m/%d/%Y" (Ej. 10/14/2010).

Comment: Why dont you use cast or convert varchar to date format and compare?

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a varchar? If it was stored as a proper date field you could use a normal 'BETWEEN' or equality testing.

Comment: Change this field type to DATE (and data itself accordingly). That's the only proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dateColumnName,'%m/%d/%Y');
```